# Plotting multiple columns from a dataframe on the y-axis using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I asked a question similar to this earlier, but can't seem to figure this one out either.

I have a list of dataframes with the same variable names. I'm able to loop through and create the plots I need using a for loop; however, I can only get one column to plot on the y-axis, and not multiple. For example, I need to plot the hourly temperatures and humidity values on the y-axis for all dataframes.

My code so far is:

```
for dataframe in li:
    plt.plot(dataframe['time'], dataframe['temp'])
```

That works to get the temperatures plotted, but I also need humidity values as well. I thought I could just do `plt.plot(dataframe['time'], dataframe['temp', 'H']` to plot both columns on the y-axis, but that does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just make another call to `plot`. Humidity will show up on the same plot.

```py
for dataframe in li:
    plt.plot(dataframe['time'], dataframe['temp'])
    plt.plot(dataframe['time'], dataframe['H'])
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick! Don't know why I didn't think of that before. Thanks so much!!